# FindViewByID Undefined For the Type Android Error

Tags: android

I have been extending from the fragment, but getting a Undefined Error For FindViewByID. Here is the Code

```
public class hashingfragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hashing, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
public void Hash(View view){
     EditText edit_text = (EditText)
             getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);

}
```

And here is the xml

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:ems="20"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:hint="Enter the Text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: `V.findViewById(R.id.editText1);`... shouldn't it be `getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);`?

Comment: It's the getView() Function, but it is still not working.

Comment: The Hash method is receiving a `View` parameter called `view` you should be using `view.findViewById(R.id.editText1)`

Comment: Post your error and your XML showing the `EditText` ID.

Comment: Why aren't you overriding the onViewCreated(...) function to obtain the reference to the EditText you are manipulating in the Hash function, using getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1)?

Comment: user2413303 can you please elaborate...

Answer (score 0):

What people are suggesting at in the comments above is:

```
public class hashingfragment extends Fragment {

    // hold on to your EditText
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                            ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hashing, container, false);
        // get your EditText here from the inflated View
        editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void Hash(View view){
        // now you can use 'editText' however you wish here
    }

}
```